# Jquery preventDefault of another function

Tags: jquery

The function in a sample of my Jquery code looks like:

```
$(document).on("click",".delete", function(del) {
    var foo='del';
    connect(foo);
    alert("connected");
});
```

And the "connect" function looks like:

```
function connect(foo){
    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
    if (networkState == Connection.NONE){   
        navigator.notification.alert('There is no connection.','','Error','Ok');    
        foo.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

What I need is to "connect" function after checking internet connectivity stops executing other functions. In this case, function "del" before executing alert.

With this code I get an error message "Uncaught ReferenceError: del is not defined at file..." What will be the right solution for this?

Comment: can you elaborate your question?

Comment: Did u included phonegap plugin? navigator.network.connection.type is a phonegap feature

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the event to the other function. Currently, you pass the string `'del'` instead of the variable `del` (the event).

```
$(document).on("click",".delete", function(event) {
    connect(event);
});
```

To avoid confusion, I suggest using `event` (or `e`) instead of `del` or `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery event handlers typically pass an object of type jQuery.Event

You need to have (or generate) an object of this type to have the `preventDefault()` function present to call on it.

You can either pass the one from the click handler, or, if you prefer, create a new one.

To use the existing click event object simply pass it through e.g.:

```
$(document).on("click",".delete", function(del) {
    connect(del);
    alert("connected");
});
```

To use a new event object:

```
var foo = jQuery.Event( "del" );
connect(foo);
```

In fact your only mistake appears to be putting quotes around `del`